# std::unordered_map<int32_t, int32_t> declared on heap

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, unordered-map

What is the syntax of declaring an std::unordered_map on the heap, performing some operations on it, and then freeing it? I'm doing:

```
std::unordered_map<int32_t, int32_t> *map_temp_last_close = new std::unordered_map<int32_t, int32_t>;
*(map_temp_last_close[val]) = *(int32_t*)(read_buffer + 30); //this happens multiple times in a loop
int32_t some_val = val * (*(map_temp_last_close[val]))
map_temp_last_close->clear();
delete(map_temp_last_close);
```

EDIT:
Why do I need to have it on the heap? I have an always running function that constantly receives data from the network and in certain cases, stores the data in a map to process it. Once the use of the map is over, I know that I will not receive that message in my protocol again and hence won't need the map, yet the map is not out of scope since the function is on an infinite loop (blocking when reading from the network). So I'd like to free up that memory by calling `free` or `delete` or something.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the heap? Why not in the stack?

Comment: @SergeRoussak see edit.

Comment: @user2635088: Local stack variables (formally, locals with automatic storage duration) are destroyed at the end of the enclosing scope, which can be smaller than a function.  Use `{}` to create a scope within a function.  Or, just call `clear()` on the `map` as you're already doing, which will recover the resources that matter (`sizeof (unordered_map)` will be negligible, it's the associated heap data that may be large enough to be of concern, and `clear()` should take care of that).

Comment: Are you saying, you are deleting the map from a different thread? If so, you should be extremely careful - make sure you used a synchronization primitive between the two threads.

Comment: @BenVoigt got it. I think `clear` should do the trick then. Thanks

Comment: @BenVoigt: Do you know, if `clear` also removes the hash table on common implementations (I guess it is not specified by the standard)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error was the positioning of the braces. You have to **first de-reference and then index** into the data structure.

I also would not put it on the heap in the first place, because  `std::unordered_map` already stores its data on the heap internally, but if you really need to, the simplest and safest way I can think of is this::

```
auto map_temp_last_close = std::make_unique<std::unordered_map<int32_t, int32_t>>() 
(*map_temp_last_close)[val] = *(int32_t*)(read_buffer + 30); 
int32_t some_val = val * (*map_temp_last_close)[val];

//map object will get destroyed automatically when map_temp_last_close goes out of scope, but if you want to delete it earlier, you can use:
map_temp_last_close.reset();
```

This creates a `std::unordered_map` on the heap and a local `unique_ptr` variable that manages it: Whenever `map_temp_last_close` goes out of scope (be it via return, an exception or just because the current scope ends), it will **automatically delete the map**. Also, there is no reason to call `clear` prior to destruction, as the map will do that automatically.

**Note:**
Most likely (depending on the type of `read_buffer`) this expression: `*(int32_t*)(read_buffer + 30)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks. So `read_buffer` is char array which i've populated upon receiving bytes from the network upon calling `recv`. If the network protocol dictates that there will be an int32_t in that position, will this still be undefined behaviour? I know that if the `int32_t` value i read is out of a certain range, then there is an error in the protocol and I can handle that behavior accordingly

Comment: @user2635088: Yes, it's undefined behavior in two ways, first is a violation of strict aliasing, second is violation of alignment (`30` is not a multiple of `sizeof (int32_t)`).  Use `memcpy(&some_val, read_buffer+30, 4)` to get the value out instead.  If you have a platform that tolerates misalignment, the compiler will generate a 32-bit move every bit as efficient as the original but the behavior is formally well defined.  And on platforms where alignment matters, you'll get working code.

Comment: @BenVoigt can I use `memcpy` to copy into (*map_temp_last_close)[val]? Would it be `memcpy(&((*map_temp_last_close)[val]), read_buffer+30, 4);`?

Comment: @user2635088: yes you can, for `std::unordered_map` and any other collection where `operator[]` returns `T&`.  Just don't try it with `std::vector<bool>`